# Why is FindObjectOfType(MyType) not finding anything?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why would I get the following log?

- Start OpponentMotionReceiver
- motion receiver not found
- true

---

```
    public class ScoreAnimation : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private OpponentMotionReceiver cachedObject;

        private void Start()
        {
            cachedObject = FindObjectOfType<OpponentMotionReceiver>();
        }

        private void OnDestroy()
        {
                var motionReceiver = FindObjectOfType<OpponentMotionReceiver>();

                if (motionReceiver == null)
                {
                    Debug.Log("motion receiver not found");
                }

                if(cachedObject != null)
                {
                    //prints true, another proof that the gameObject is active
                    Debug.Log(cachedObject.gameObject.activeInHierarchy);
                }
        }
    }

public class OpponentMotionReceiver : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private void Start()
        {
            Debug.Log("Start OpponentMotionReceiver");
        }

        private void OnDisable()
        {
            Debug.Log("OnDisable OpponentMotionReceiver");
        }

        private void OnDestroy()
        {
            Debug.Log("OnDestroy OpponentMotionReceiver");
        }
    }
```

P.S. This is extremely simplified version of the code so that the rest brings no confusion. If you need more details, I'd be pleased to answer you!

Comment: IS the Motion reciever being used in the scene?

Comment: Yeah it is [a few more characters]

Comment: Even in the full version of the code, in the Start() in ScoreAnimation I use `FindObjectOfType<OpponentMotionReceiver>()` again, and successfully.

Comment: Could you cache the object returned in Start()?  Then check if that refernce is null OnDestroy()?

Comment: Just did, and it looks fine(it is not null when checked OnDestroy())

Comment: Just to make sure that I haven't missed something, here is the way I checked for the cached object http://pastebin.com/Yh3TQa07

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the scene. Only at that time unity behaves like that. No matter if the object we are looking for is active or not, simply FindObjectOfType doesn't work at this point of the game cycle.

From https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/112783/59620

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to call method by using typeof i.e.`FindObjectOfType(typeof(OpponentMotionReceiver))` as stated in [official document](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) ?

Comment: I just did and got same results

Comment: Have you tried to declare motionReceiver  as OpponentMotionReceiver rather than var ?

Comment: Also, with some hesitation, i remember that this method find objects that exist in current scene, are you sure you've the object in the current scene?

Comment: About the explicit definition of the variable, just tried and again same results, although really didn't think this could be the issue I was afraid not to try :D As for the object in the scene, yes it is in the scene.

Answer (score 0):

When OnDestroy is called in your component the `GameObject` is already deactivated. It's likely already torn out of the normal hierarchy.

Also, if the scene is leaving, it looks like all `GameObject` instances in the scene that are not set to `DontDestroyOnLoad` are first deactivated.

When `OnDestroy` is called all the objects you are looking for are already deactivated.